# Blank Screen from phpinfo

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I've been using Xampp for a php site and decided it was redundant, uninstalled it in favor of the lamp-server with:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Apache2 is working fine on test.
I replaced the Apache2 default page with test.php that only has

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it.

on "http://localhost/test.php" I get only a white screen.

When I inspected it in the firefox console the error message

"The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

is there, and I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this issue on my own.

I haven't come across anything that addresses this specific problem.
Can I request some guidance and answers from the community please? I use Linux Mint Ulyana.
Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: As I was looking into it a experimenting with some seemingly innocuous and harmless fixes I tried adding only a charset -
So tried this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And also tried with full html tags.

The error message changed to this:

"GEThttp://localhost/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]"

I'm starting to feel like this may be something left over from Xampp, and will be looking into that after I finish this edit. Until then, if anyone knows anything please share

Comment: We do not support mint.  Please use U+L for your questions https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mint is unsupported, but this is the code I use: `<?php phpinfo( ); ?>` Note the space. I have no idea if that's your problem however.